# It does not show formula result until refreshed manually

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

When I put a formula in a cell using Excel VBA, It does not show the formula result until I manually goto the cell and click the formula bar, and press enter.

I have tried calculating range, calculate sheet etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49743732/turn-on-off-automatic-calculation-in-only-a-few-columns-in-excel

Comment: It's likely you ran some code that turned it off, but then it errored and stopped before it could complete, so the code to turn it back on never ran.